# How to make tr aware of non-ascii(unicode) characters?

Tags: linux, text-processing, unicode, tr

I'm trying to remove some characters from file(UTF-8). I'm using `tr` for this purpose:

```sh
tr -cs '[[:alpha:][:space:]]' ' ' <testdata.dat
```

File contains some foreign characters (like "Латвийская" or "àé"). `tr` doesn't seem to understand them: it treats them as non-alpha and removes too.

I've tried changing some of my locale settings:

```sh
LC_CTYPE=C LC_COLLATE=C tr -cs '[[:alpha:][:space:]]' ' ' <testdata.dat
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=C tr -cs '[[:alpha:][:space:]]' ' ' <testdata.dat
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.UTF-8 tr -cs '[[:alpha:][:space:]]' ' ' <testdata.dat
```

Unfortunately, none of these worked.

How can I make `tr` understand Unicode?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That's a known ([1](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20114), [2](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=9365), [3](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=9569), [4](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10880), [5](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12192), [6](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13362)) limitation of the GNU implementation of `tr`.

It's not as much that it doesn't support *foreign*, non-English or non-ASCII characters, but that it doesn't support multi-byte characters.

Those Cyrillic characters would be treated OK, if written in the iso8859-5 (single-byte per character) character set (and your locale was using that charset), but your problem is that you're using UTF-8 where non-ASCII characters are encoded in 2 or more bytes.

GNU's got [a plan](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/coreutils_i18n/) (see [also](http://crashcourse.housegordon.org/coreutils-multibyte-support.html)) to fix that and work is under way but not there yet.

FreeBSD or Solaris `tr` don't have the problem.

---

In the mean time, for most use cases of `tr`, you can use GNU sed or GNU awk which do support multi-byte characters.

For instance, your:

```
tr -cs '[[:alpha:][:space:]]' ' '
```

could be written:

```
gsed -E 's/( |[^[:space:][:alpha:]])+/ /'
```

or:

```
gawk -v RS='( |[^[:space:][:alpha:]])+' '{printf "%s", sep $0; sep=" "}'
```

To convert between lower and upper case (`tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`):

```
gsed 's/[[:upper:]]/\l&/g'
```

(that `l` is a lowercase `L`, not the `1` digit).

or:

```
gawk '{print tolower($0)}'
```

For portability, `perl` is another alternative:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/([^[:space:][:alpha:]]| )+/ /g'
perl -Mopen=locale -pe '$_=lc$_'
```

If you know the data can be represented in a single-byte character set, then you can process it in that charset:

```
(export LC_ALL=ru_RU.iso88595
 iconv -f utf-8 |
   tr -cs '[:alpha:][:space:]' ' ' |
   iconv -t utf-8) < Russian-file.utf8
```

Comment: I've accepted your question because of information about tr. I've solved the problem, and removed question about how to solve it(so people looking for tr will find only information about tr, not some arbitrary problem). If you could please remove solution too, since it's no longer needed, I'd be thankful.

Comment: @MatthewRock I've kept it but reworded it and made more generic as giving a word around would be useful to people with the same problem.

Comment: Where do you get an idea that Cyrillic is (customarily) encoded in ISO 8859-5? Did you ever see a Russian text in anything but Unicode?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, all that matters here is that ISO 8859-5 is one of those singe-byte charsets that has those Cyrillic characters. Whether it's in widespread use or not is irrelevant here. If you have a locale with KOI-R or window-1251 charset, by all means, use it instead.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Russian on the web is almost always encoded in UTF-8 (or occasionally in Windows-1251), but only because we’ve felt the pain of many single-byte encodings early on. Here’s an ancient (circa 1998) web page with a (non-functional) encoding switcher: http://sch57.ru/collect/.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Windows, however, still uses Windows-1251 in many places and IBM866 (aka “GOST alternative”, “Alt”) in the terminal. Try getting your Python 2 script with Russian output to run in both Windows terminal and IDLE, it’s _fun_.

Answer (score 5):

Just use GNU sed (with appropriate `LANG` environment var., like `en_US.UTF-8`):

```
% sed 'y/123/abc/; y/āōī/456/' <<< test123ingmāōī
testabcingm456
```