# How do I extract only alphanumeric characters from a given text file and print them?

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file that looks like the text that is pasted below.  I want to extract to a file any characters that are alphanumeric in nature, and ignore everything else.

What is the easiest way to do this (`grep`, `cut`)?

```
%[{]$#{!^]^$#+*$}#*)(]!@^&#){][$)}!+%^)@#&!%(+^^($(%}^+[*)#+{%!))}(*&]__})][_))}#
%())#&##{]$#$](&$%&&$)^{(@%)$%()#)&&*{]&^^+%$##%{!(_$(**&(_]+{%[%$!_){$*@@++]&^$(
%@+{+&%]$)+@({$(+{!*#(%)]+[}){]]#)*[]%&{+)$){!&$]+^++_@]#%)[&&^%]#@#@)]@}%$[_*@%)
%[&*^*})@(!{&^#!([%@_![{)+)$}_+)%&^#@#$$}))^&)}({+*&_()&@]$^#(&&{){)_[}{@(}#)!)%&
%({+$[!#()[]%{$_*]*^%&]@{^@{)}}_^}@!^*)_[([{}]{*#{]&}}[$_[}!%%&_{{!$[}&[[@#[&_$()
%*_$+)&}*){${}!]+%[{{!+)+{!&]$!}{_]&)!!^+){&*#{@!##_(^%^$([!+&+($&)##[&[^_{##{(**
%{{)#*%@*[(^(}!%}@*}@+]^_}&&&}&{[$(@[#*+%[&%{$$**]]%(!$+$!]^+[^_(&*{#_^%[[#+{]#_[
%*}]#)!%!_[})^%*@{!{$)*_+$$*}%(&]%^+$@!&{[]}**})}#}[#{%{$#@##(])&)((${^]^[%^&(!_&
```

Comment: I may have answered my own question.  Here's the command I used: 'grep -oE "[[:alnum:]]" findnormalchars.txt'

Comment: Sorry if this was a bad question, first time posting.  Working through bash scripting exercises.

Answer (score 6):

For ASCII alphanumeric characters only:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:alnum:]' <file
```

For alphanumeric characters [according to your locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745/38906), just:

```
tr -cd '[:alnum:]' <file
```

or defining the locale explicitly:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 tr -cd '[:alnum:]' <file
```

[(An exception is GNU tr, which does not support multi-bytes characters currently)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228570/38906)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any alphanumeric characters in there, but this sed command should work `sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' /tmp/foobar` where `/tmp/foobar` is the input file.

`s/a/b/` means replace any instance of a with b, `[^a-z]` means any character that is not a through z.`s/a/b/g` means do this globally, rather than stopping at the first instance on each line, keep on doing this.

Comment: for a really in depth look into regular expressions, I'd recommend checking this book out: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do :)