# How can I convert Persian numerals in UTF-8 to European numerals in ASCII?

Tags: bash, unicode, conversion

In Persian numerals, `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` is equivalent to `0123456789` in European digits.

How can I convert Persian number ( in `UTF-8` ) to ASCII?

For example, I want `۲۱` to become `21`.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like `echo "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT` doesn't handle it...

Comment: @Kusalananda NOT worked

Comment: @Kusalananda: Is it really that unexpected? As I understood it `iconv` is just here to map characters in different encodings, but these are characters (Eastern Arabic numerals) that have no equivalent in ASCII, you can just convert them to something similar enough but it's one-way only.

Comment: Well, I wasn't quite sure what `iconv` was capable and not capable of doing. I was hoping thot using `//TRANSLIT` would help, but it didn't.

Comment: Do you also need to reverse the order?  I know that Arabic numerals are written little-endian right-to-left, and Latin numerals are big-endian left-to-right (looking similar in print or on screen, but reversed in memory).  Is Persian the same?

Comment: @TobySpeight : no reverse; arabic and persian numberic is left-to-right like european digit,, only alphabet is write right-to-left

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can take advantage of the fact that the UNICODE code point of Persian numerals are [consecutive and ordered from 0 to 9](http://sartre2.byu.edu/persian/persianword/numbers.htm):

```
$ printf '%b' '\U06F'{0..9}
۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹
```

That means that the last hex digit IS the decimal value:

```
$ echo $(( $(printf '%d' "'۲") & 0xF ))
2
```

That makes this simple loop a conversion tool:

```
#!/bin/bash
(   ### Use a locale that use UTF-8 to make the script more reliable.
    ### Maybe something like LC_ALL=fa_IR.UTF-8 for you?.
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
    a="$1"
    while (( ${#a} > 0 )); do
        # extract the last hex digit from the UNICODE code point
        # of the first character in the string "$a":
        printf '%d' $(( $(printf '%d' "'$a") & 15 ))
        a=${a#?}    ## Remove one character from $a
    done
)
echo
```

Using it as:

```
$ sefr.sh ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹
0123456789

$ sefr.sh ۲۰۱
201

$ sefr.sh ۲۱
21
```

Note that this code could also convert Arabic and Latin numerals (even if mixed):

```
$ sefr.sh ۴4٤۵5٥۶6٦۷7٧۸8٨۹9٩
444555666777888999

$ sefr.sh ٤٧0٠٦7١٣3٥۶٦۷
4700671335667
```

Comment: very very thanks, this is very nice solution,, and i have question ,,in this command  printf '%d' '"۰' why use double-quotation ?

Comment: @Babyy It is not a double quotation, it is a way to give printf an argument that start with a single quote: `'۰`. It could have been written also as `'"۰'`. The reason is that printf will give the UNICODE code point if the argument starts with a single quote `'` or a double quote `"`. Search a little [before this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_14) for the text "If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote"

Comment: @Babyy The code has been extended to convert Persian, Arabic, and Latin (even if mixed).

Answer (score 30):

Since it's a fixed set of numbers, you can do it by hand:

```
$ echo ۲۱ | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sed -e 'y/۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹/0123456789/'
21
```

(or using `tr`, but [not GNU tr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228558/38906) yet)

Setting your locale to `en_US.utf8` (or better to the locale which characters set belongs to) is required for `sed` to recognize your characters set.

With `perl`:

```
$ echo "۲۱" |
  perl -CS -MUnicode::UCD=num -MUnicode::Normalize -lne 'print num(NFKD($_))'
21
```

Comment: Setting the `LC_ALL` is needed so that every single unicode characters will be also considered as such by `sed`, right?

Comment: @phk: Yes, see the updating.

Comment: Why must everything be a sed script?  Didn't we invent `tr` for this exact purpose?

Comment: @Kevin See the other answer involving `tr` how it does not work everywhere. Also keep in mind that some tools are optimized for dealing with bytes while others are for dealing with characters, with Unicode (especially UTF-8) this makes a huge difference.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me on OS X 10.10.5/GNU bash 4.3. Weirdly enough I need to *remove* the explicit setting of `LC_ALL`. `LC_ALL` is also not set in my environment (but `LANG` is set to `en_GB.UTF-8`). With the above code, I get the error “sed: 1: "y/۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹/ ...": transform strings are not the same length”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Check if your locale has `en_US.utf8`. What command did you run? How about setting `LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8`?

Comment: @cuonglm Indeed, when I replace `utf8` with `UTF-8` it works. In fact, I’ve never heard of the spelling without the dash. Might this be a typo in your answer or do some systems use that name? (EDIT, found this: http://superuser.com/a/999151/2269)

Answer (score 16):

For Python there is the `unidecode` library which handles such conversions in general: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode.

In Python 2:

```python
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(u"۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹")
'0123456789'
```

In Python 3:

```python
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode("۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹")
'0123456789'
```

The SO thread at https://stackoverflow.com/q/8087381/2261442 might be related.

/edit: 
As Wander Nauta pointed out in the comments and as mentioned on the Unidecode page there is also a shell version of `unidecode` (under `/usr/local/bin/` if installed over `pip`):

```bash
$ echo '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹' | unidecode
0123456789
```

Comment: The unidecode library also ships a utility called (unsurprisingly) `unidecode` which does the same as your Python 3 snippet. Just `echo '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹' | unidecode` should work.

Comment: @Wander - the Debian package of python-unidecode doesn't ship the utility program, so the long form may be necessary on such platforms (I didn't find one in the source tarball from upstream, so perhaps the program is something added by your distribution?)

Comment: @TobySpeight If you install it using `pip` it's there.

Comment: @TobySpeight The utility is in the upstream tarball as `unidecode/util.py` - strange that Debian doesn't include it. (Edit: Ah, mystery solved. The Debian package is out of date and older than the utility.)

Answer (score 8):

A pure bash version:

```
#!/bin/bash

number="$1"

number=${number//۱/1}
number=${number//۲/2}
number=${number//۳/3}
number=${number//۴/4}
number=${number//۵/5}
number=${number//۶/6}
number=${number//۷/7}
number=${number//۸/8}
number=${number//۹/9}
number=${number//۰/0}

echo "Result is $number"
```

Have tested in my Gentoo machine and it works.

```
./convert ۱۳۲
Result is 132
```

---

Done as a loop, given the list of characters (from 0 to 9) to convert:

```
#!/bin/bash
conv() ( LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
         local n="$2"
         for ((i=0;i<${#1};i++)); do
              n=${n//"${1:i:1}"/"$i"}
         done
         printf '%s\n' "$n"
       )

conv "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹" "$1"
```

And used as:

```
$ convert ۱۳۲
132
```

Another (rather overkill) way using `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

nums=$(echo "$1" | grep -o .)
result=()

for i in $nums
do
    case $i in
        ۱)
            result+=1
            ;;
        ۲)
            result+=2
            ;;
        ۳)
            result+=3
            ;;
        ۴)
            result+=4
            ;;
        ۵)
            result+=5
            ;;
        ۶)
            result+=6
            ;;
        ۷)
            result+=7
            ;;
        ۸)
            result+=8
            ;;
        ۹)
            result+=9
            ;;
        ۰)
            result+=0
            ;;
    esac
done
echo "Result is $result"
```

Comment: Pure Bash, except for the `grep`. In fact, I don't understand that line, nor why you do not set `result=0`. Are you being overly cautious in case `$1` contains things other than Farsi digits?

Comment: @Kusalananda that line reads the Farsi digits into nums. Makes it loop-able.

Comment: Ten simple substitutions would have been quicker... `number=${number//۱/1}` etc., and would avoid the `echo` and `grep`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Nice. Changed it. Now it is pure Bash! ;-)

Comment: @coffeMug : ۱۳۲ is 132 no 123 :D

Comment: @Babyy Damn copy paste! And you have sharp eyes. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since `iconv` can't seem to grok this, the next port of call would be to use the `tr` utility:

```
$ echo "۲۱" | tr '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹' '0123456789'
21
```

`tr` translates one set of characters to another, so we simply tell it to translate the set of Farsi digits to the set of Latin digits.

**EDIT**: As user @cuonglm points out. This requires non-GNU `tr`, for example the `tr` on a Mac, and it also requires that `$LC_CTYPE` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Note that it won't work with GNU tr, which does not support multi-byte characters.

Comment: Oh my. Silly GNU.  ;-)

Comment: And also you need to set your locale to the one which supports unicode, like `en_US.utf8`.

Answer (score 1):

`numconv` is in the repository of some Linux distros, Debian and Ubuntu, at least. Install `numconv`.

```
$ echo '۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰' | numconv
1234567890
```

(Edit: Note that leading zeros are removed, and that this is purely for numeric conversion, and will not work with streams that contain non-numeric characters as well.)