# tr analog for unicode characters?

Tags: unicode, utilities, tr

I need internationalized utility that does the same thing as `tr`: gets character from stream and substitutes it with a corresponding character.
Not a particular case solution like lower-to-upper, but a general case solution is needed.
Without gorillion piped `sed` calls if possible.

Note that `tr` does not work on Linux: it translates bytes, not characters. This fails with multibyte encodings.

```
$ tr --version | head -n 1
tr (GNU coreutils) 8.23
$ echo $LC_CTYPE
en_US.UTF-8
$ echo 'Ångstrom' | tr Æ Œ         
Ņngstrom
```

Comment: Similar: [How to make tr aware of non-ascii(unicode) characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/228558)

Comment: Gilles' example given here does not exhibit that problem with FreeBSD `tr` in a UTF-8 locale.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GNU `sed` does work with multi-byte characters. So:

```
$ echo é½Æ | sed 'y/é½Æ/ABŒ/'
ABŒ
```

It's not so much that GNU `tr` hasn't been internationalised but that it doesn't support multi-byte characters (like the non-ASCII ones in UTF-8 locales). GNU `tr` would work with `Æ`, `Œ` as long as they were single-byte like in the iso8859-15 character set.

More on that at [How to make tr aware of non-ascii(unicode) characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228558)

In any case, that has nothing to do with Linux, it's about the `tr` implementation on the system. Whether that system uses Linux as a kernel or `tr` is built for Linux or use the Linux kernel API is not relevant as that part of the `tr` functionality takes place in user space.

busybox `tr` and GNU `tr` are the most commonly found on distributions of software built for Linux and don't support multi-byte characters, but there are others that have been ported to Linux like the `tr` of the heirloom toolchest (ported from OpenSolaris) or of ast-open that do.

Note that `sed`'s `y` doesn't support ranges like `a-z`. Also note that if that script that contains `sed 'y/é½Æ/ABŒ/'` is written in the UTF-8 charset, it will no longer work as expected if called in a locale where UTF-8 is not the charset.

An alternative could be to use `perl`:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -pe 'y/a-zé½Æ/A-ZABŒ/'
```

Above, the perl code is expected to be in UTF-8, but it will process the input in the locale's encoding (and output in that same encoding). If called in a UTF-8 locale, it will transliterate a UTF-8 `Æ` (0xc3 0x86) to a UTF-8 `Œ` (0xc5 0x92) and in a ISO8859-15 same but for 0xc6 -> 0xbc.

In most shells, having those UTF-8 characters inside the single quotes should be OK even if the script is called in a locale where UTF-8 is not the charset (an exception is `yash` which would complain if those bytes don't form valid characters in the locale). If you're using other quoting than single-quotes, however, it could cause problems. For instance,

```
perl -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -pe "y/♣\`/&'/"
```

would fail in a locale where the charset is BIG5-HKSCS because the encoding of `\` (0x5c) also happens  to be contained in some other characters there (like `α`: 0xa3 0x5c, and the UTF-8 encoding of `♣` happens to end in 0xa3).

In any case, don't expect things like

```
perl -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -pe 'y/Á-Ź/A-Z/'
```

to work at removing acute accents. The above is actually just

```
perl -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -pe 'y/\x{c1}-\x{179}/\x{41}-\x{5a}/'
```

That is, the range is based on the unicode codepoints. So ranges won't be useful outside of very well defined sequences that happen to be in the "*right*" order in Unicode like `A-Z`, `0-9`.

If you want to remove acute accents, you'd have to use more advanced tools like:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -MUnicode::Normalize -pe '
  $_ = NFKD($_); s/\x{301}//g; $_ = NFKC($_)'
```

That is use Unicode normalisation forms to decompose characters, remove the acute accents (here the combining form `U+0301`) and recompose.

Another useful tool to transliterate Unicode is `uconv` from [ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode). For instance, the above could also be written as:

```
uconv -x '::NFKD; \u0301>; ::NFKC;'
```

Though would only work on UTF-8 data. You'd need:

```
iconv -t utf-8 | uconv -x '::NFKD; \u0301>; ::NFKC;' | iconv -f utf-8
```

To be able to process data in the user's locale.

Comment: The perl solution appears to only work partly: `echo 'été à la plage' | perl -Mopen=locale -MUnicode::Normalize -pe '$_ = NFKD($_); s/\x{301}//g; $_ = NFKC($_)'` shows `ete à la plage`, i.e. the é got changed, but not the à.

Comment: Ah I see, I need to remove \x{300} as well. Sorry for the noise. Hope it helps someone one day ;)

Comment: @DavidFaure or `s/\pM//g` to remove every combining mark if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, you can use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace).

Substituting `Å` successfully:

```
$ string='Hello Ångstrom'
$ a='Å'
$ b='Œ'
$ printf '%s\n' "${string//${a}/${b}}"
Hello Œngstrom
```

Trying to substitute `Æ`, which is not part of the string:

```
$ string='Hello Ångstrom'
$ a='Æ'
$ b='Œ'
$ printf '%s\n' "${string//${a}/${b}}"
Hello Ångstrom
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be your encoding scheme.  Try running it through iconv like this:

```
echo Ångstrom | iconv -f UTF-8 | tr 'Å' 'Œ'
```

Comes out with: Œngstrom

Comment: This is only a side effect of tr replacing both bytes of a multibyte character separately. `tr 'Å' '1'` results in incorrect `11ngstrom`.