# Ignore part of the string with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

so, I have files with text formatted like this:

```
untranslatedString : "translated string",
```

and I need to replace characters in "translated string" part with their Cyrillic representation. I use something like this:

```
paste <(sed 's/\([^:]\+:\)\([^:]\+\)/\1/' resources.js) <(sed 's/[^:]\+:\([^:]\+\)/\1/;y/abc/абц/' resources.js)
```

(abc/абц/ part is actually longer and includes all characters, this is for illustrative purposes).

problem arises in lines like this one:

```
abcTestString : "abc {ccb} bbc",
```

everything between {} should be left in it's original state, ie. character shouldn't be replaced. result should be:

```
abcTestString : "aбц {ccb} ббц",
```

and not

```
abcTestString : "aбц {ццб} ббц",
```

Also, there can be multiple {} parts per line.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay with using `perl`

```
$ s='abcTestString : "abc {ccb} bbc",'
$ echo "$s" | perl -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -F: -lane '
               $F[-1]=~s/\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z]+/$&=~tr|abc|абц|r/ge;
               print join ":",@F'
abcTestString : "абц {ccb} ббц",
```

- `-Mopen=locale -Mutf8` unicode settings (thanks to this wonderful answer [tr analog for unicode characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389615/tr-analog-for-unicode-characters))
- `-F: -lane` use `:` as field separator, saved in `@F` array (See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for other options)
- `$F[-1]` last field of `@F` array
- `\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z]+` here we say that `[a-z]+` portion has to match but `\{[^{}]+\}` should be left as it is
- `$&=~tr|abc|абц|r` perform transliteration for the matched portion
- `ge` the `g` modifier for replacing all matches, `e` modifier to allow the Perl code in replacement section

If this is too big a code to handle from command line, change it to a program

```
$ echo "$s" | perl -MO=Deparse -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -F: -lane '
               $F[-1]=~s/\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z]+/$&=~tr|abc|абц|r/ge;
               print join ":",@F'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
use open (split(/,/, 'locale', 0));
use utf8;
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    our @F = split(/:/, $_, 0);
    $F[-1] =~ s[\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z]+][use utf8 ();
    $& =~ tr/abc/\x{430}\x{431}\x{446}/r;]eg;
    print join(':', @F);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stay with `sed`:

```
sed 's/"/"_/;:l
  s/_[^{]*/&_/;h
  s/.*_\(.*\)_.*/\1/
  y/abc/абц/;G
  s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)_.*_\([^}]*}\)\{0,1\}/\2\1\3_/
  /_$/!bl
  s/_//'
```

An underscore is used as mark during processing. If underscores can be part of the file, use a different delimiter.

The idea is to mark a part of the string, save a copy to hold space, remove everything outside the marks, do your conversion, get back the copy, compose a string with the converted part and move the underscore forward. If there is a part in `{}`, skip that.

I can give a more detailed explanation, if you are interested.

Comment: Hmm, I am having problem with this line:  /_$/!bl

Comment: The underscore will will moved to the right after each part. If it is not yet moved to the end of the string (`/ _$/!`), jump to the start of the loop (`bl` means `b`ranch to mark `:l`).

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -rf <(echo ':l'; printf 's/("| [^{]*)%s/\\1%s/g\n' a а b б c ц; echo 'tl') input.txt
```

Or more concisely, but also more prone to errors, because the `sed`'s expression is enclosed in double quotes, not in single quotes, so `bash` special characters should be escaped, for example the `$` sign.

```
sed -r ":l; $(printf 's/("| [^{]*)%s/\\1%s/g;' a а b б c ц) tl" input.txt
```

**Explanation** (the first command were taken)

`sed -f script-file` - add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed.

`<()` - process substitution. It allows represent the commands output as a file and pass it to the command, which is expecting a file.

`echo ':l'; printf 's/("| [^{]*)%s/\\1%s/g\n' a а b б c ц; echo 'tl'` - it is converting to the next `sed`'s commands sequence:

```
:l
s/("| [^{]*)a/\1а/g
s/("| [^{]*)b/\1б/g
s/("| [^{]*)c/\1ц/g
tl
```

#### Testing:

**Input**

```
abcTestString : "abc {bcb} bbc",
abcTestString : "bbc {acb} bbc {bcb}",
abcTestString : "acc {cab} {ccb} bbc",
abcTestString : "cbc {ccb} bac {aca} bac",
```

**Output**

```
abcTestString : "абц {bcb} ббц",
abcTestString : "ббц {acb} ббц {bcb}",
abcTestString : "ацц {cab} {ccb} ббц",
abcTestString : "цбц {ccb} бац {aca} бац",
```