# Is this a bug in 'tr'?

Tags: unicode, tr

My terminal is set to UTF-8. If I type this:

```
echo -n 'ýá' | xxd
```

I can see this output:

```
00000000: c3bd c3a1
```

Which is fine. Now I would like to remove the 'ý' character from the string, so I use:

```
echo -n 'ýá' | tr -d 'ý' | xxd
```

But the result will be:

```
00000000: a1
```

The `tr` removes also the next `c3` byte, but that is part of the 'á' character. Why is working this way? Is this a bug? Or should I set something?

Comment: I think `tr` works on the byte level and the UTF-8 characters you show are represented by 2 bytes and one of those bytes is common in both UTF-8 characters. I think it is not a bug, but the way this primitive tool works. (You can test with some characters that are represented by single bytes and see what happens when some of them are represented twice in the pattern.)

Comment: so `tr` is not prepared for UTF-8 ?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate - [How to make tr aware of non-ascii(unicode) characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228570/100397) and [tr analog for unicode characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389641/100397)

Comment: yes, now it's clear