# replacement for tr with utf-8 capabilities

Tags: text-processing, unicode, character-encoding, text, tr

in order to isolate the last word in any line of a poem (to have a list of all rhymes), I put together several snippets of code obtaining this

```
awk '{print $NF}' input.txt | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'  | tr -sc 'a-z' '\n' | rev |  sort | uniq | sort -d | rev
```

applying it to poems like this:

```
Se a ciascun l'interno affanno
Si leggesse in fronte scritto
Quanti mai, che invidia fanno
Ci farebbero pietà!
```

I get

```
fanno
affanno
scritto
piet
```

As you can see, the word "**pietà**" lacks of accented character. I guess this depends from having not tr UTF-8 capabilities. Is there any replacement for tr able to perfprm the same task in this one liner, but retaining UTF-8 accented characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limitation of the GNU implementation of `tr` with regards to multibyte characters and some of its alternatives are covered in [tr analog for unicode characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389615).

Here, you can do everything in `awk` (the GNU implementation at least supports multibyte characters and localisation):

```
< yourfile awk '{
  last = tolower($NF)
  gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/, "\n", last)
  print last}' |
  rev | sort -u | rev
```

Which gives:

```
pietà
fanno
affanno
scritto
```

Or if the intention is to get the last sequence of letters from each line, with `perl` (with which you can also do all the decoding as per locale, conversion to lowercase, reverse, locale collation sorting):

```
<your-file perl -Mopen=locale -MPOSIX -lne '
  $word{lc $1}++ if /(\p{Letter}+)\P{Letter}*$/;
  END {
    print $_->[0] for
      sort {strcoll($a->[1], $b->[1])}
      map {[$_, scalar reverse $_]} keys %word
  }'
```

Or with GNU tools:

```
<yourfile grep -Po '\pL+(?=\PL*$)' | sed 's/.*/\L&/' | rev | sort -u | rev
```

Or doing the last sequence of letter extraction with `sed`:

```
<yourfile sed -E '/([[:alpha:]]+)[^[:alpha:]]*$/!d;s//\n\L\1/;s/.*\n//' |
  rev | sort -u | rev
```

Which can be easier if done after the first `rev`:

```
<yourfile rev |
  sed -nE 's/^[^[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]]+).*$/\L\1/p' |
  sort -u | rev
```

Comment: @Quasímodo, my understanding is that the OP's `tr -cs` is to split things like `l'interno` into `l` and `interno`.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a.=push: .comb(/<alpha>+/)[*-1] if .chars for lines;  \
        .put for @a.unique>>.flip.sort( *.fc.trans: "àèéìòù" => "aeeiou" )>>.flip;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'my @a.=push: .comb(/<alpha>+/)[*-1] if .chars for lines; \
        .put for @a.unique.map(*.flip).sort( *.fc.trans: "àèéìòù" => "aeeiou" ).map(*.flip);'
```

Above are answers coded in [Raku](https://raku.org), which is built to handle Unicode by default. Briefly, if `lines` contain `chars` characters  (i.e. are not blank), `push` the `[*-1]` last-element of a line that has been `comb`ed through via regex looking for `<alpha>+` one-or-more alphabetic characters (positive-selection for desired elements, as opposed to a destructive `split`). [Note, here `words` would be a close approximation, except `words` only splits on whitespace and thus would still leave punctuation characters in the resultant elements].

Once `@a` array is filled ( *here `my @a.=push( … )` de-sugars to `my @a = @a.push( … )`* ), elements of @a are `unique`-ified, `flip`ped, `sort`ed, and `flip`ped back.

Sorting is accomplished with the routine/parameters `.sort( *.fc.trans: "àèéìòù" => "aeeiou" )`, meaning that `*` elements are sorted on characters that have been `fc` **[case-folded](https://docs.raku.org/routine/fc)** as well as the six accented characters `trans`lated: `"àèéìòù" => "aeeiou"`. Without the `trans` routine, words ending in those six accented characters sort to the end of the list.

Sample Input:

```
Se a ciascun l'interno affanno
Si leggesse in fronte scritto
Quanti mai, che invidia fanno
Ci farebbero pietà!
```

Sample Output:

```
pietà
fanno
affanno
scritto
```

I took the liberty of testing another poem by Pietro Metastasio entitled [La libertà](https://www.poesieracconti.it/poesie/a/pietro-metastasio/la-liberta). Sample Output is shown below, however I added `.join(", ")` at the end of the code to return comma-separated output (instead of one-word-per-line). First answer below ***with*** the call to `trans: "àèéìòù" => "aeeiou"`, second answer below ***without*** the call to `trans: "àèéìòù" => "aeeiou"`:

```bsh
~$ perl6 -e 'my @a.=push: .comb(/<alpha>+/)[*-1] if .chars for lines; .put for @a.unique.map(*.flip).sort( *.fc.trans: "àèéìòù" => "aeeiou" ).map(*.flip).join(", "); put("");' file.txt
fa, ha, bella, quella, pena, catena, ragiona, sprona, ancora, talora, pietà, beltà, sciolta, volta, libertà, rinnova, prova, è, piace, spiace, infelice, Nice, ingannatrice, fé, me, penne, avvenne, core, ardore, colore, rossore, te, amante, incostante, fai, mai, guai, spezzai, dì, miei, sei, sdegni, segni, suoi, tuoi, così, dico, antico, parlando, dimando, umano, vano, sdegno, segno, hanno, sanno, dono, ragiono, sono, sincero, primiero, impero, altero, vero, aggiro, miro, curo, procuro, so, passò, appresso, oppresso, stesso, istesso, ingrato, prato, ascolto, volto, cimento, rammento, sento, contento, estinto, istinto, difetto, aspetto, consolar, parlar, sdegnar, trovar, piacer, pensier, soffrir, morir, cor, amor, favor

~$ perl6 -e 'my @a.=push: .comb(/<alpha>+/)[*-1] if .chars for lines; .put for @a.unique.map(*.flip).sort( *.fc ).map(*.flip).join(", "); put("");' file.txt
fa, ha, bella, quella, pena, catena, ragiona, sprona, ancora, talora, sciolta, volta, rinnova, prova, piace, spiace, infelice, Nice, ingannatrice, me, penne, avvenne, core, ardore, colore, rossore, te, amante, incostante, fai, mai, guai, spezzai, miei, sei, sdegni, segni, suoi, tuoi, dico, antico, parlando, dimando, umano, vano, sdegno, segno, hanno, sanno, dono, ragiono, sono, sincero, primiero, impero, altero, vero, aggiro, miro, curo, procuro, so, appresso, oppresso, stesso, istesso, ingrato, prato, ascolto, volto, cimento, rammento, sento, contento, estinto, istinto, difetto, aspetto, consolar, parlar, sdegnar, trovar, piacer, pensier, soffrir, morir, cor, amor, favor, pietà, beltà, libertà, è, fé, dì, così, passò
```

*Caveat: because all punctuation gets removed, hyphenated words (if any) are split into component words during analysis.*