# How to translate Unicode characters?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, tr

I'm trying to convert some characters to the fullwidth form like this

```
tr 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 'ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ'
```

However, it doesn't work. I did a search and it turns out [`tr` doesn't support UTF-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228558/44425). So based on the answer on that question I tried to use perl

```perl
perl -C -pe 'tr/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ/'
```

But still no help. I tried simpler versions of it

```perl
$ echo abca | perl -C -pe 's/a/ａ/g'
ï½bcï½
$ echo abca | perl -C -pe 'tr/a/ａ/'
ïbcï
```

It seems perl still treats multibyte UTF-8 characters as bytes

How can I convert those characters properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both GNU and BSD `sed` are multibyte-aware in appropriate locales, and the [`y` command is analogous to `tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03):

```
$ echo hello | sed -e 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ/'
ｈｅｌｌｏ
```

This should work most places you're likely to run it, as long as your locale is a UTF-8 one.

---

The Perl issue isn't quite as simple as treating multibyte characters as bytes. It's understanding your input just fine, and even encoding the output, it's the *source code* it doesn't understand:

```
$ echo abc | perl -C -pe 'tr/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ/'|hexdump -C
00000000  c3 af c2 bd c2 81 0a                              |.......|
```

The UTF-8 encoding of "ａ" is `ef bd 81`, so you can see that it's treating "b" as that second byte and then mangling it trying to encode it on the way out, and the same for "c". You [need to `use utf8` to have your Perl (5) source itself encoded in that way](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html); `-C` only controls IO the program does when it's running.

You can put `use utf8;` into your `-e` string, or [use `-Mutf8` on the command line](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

```
$ echo abc | perl -C -Mutf8 -pe 'tr/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ/'
ａｂｃ
```

Perl 6 does solve this issue, as so many, but...